# EmailMessage.ToAddress - Illegal assignment: from list to string

Tags: apex, email

I'm creating an email to custom object class which creates a record on the "Trade Support" object along with the emails attachment(s) if any and wanting to attach the email message to the record as well via the EmailMessage object.

I have everything working minus the EmailMessage portion of this.  When I try to list the toAddress, I'm getting an error of

> "Illegal assignment: from list to string"

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to create a list and attach that list to the "toAddress" field of the emailMessage that attaches to the case.

Here is my code:

```
global class CreateTradeSupport implements Messaging.InboundEmailHandler {

    global Messaging.InboundEmailResult handleInboundEmail(Messaging.InboundEmail email, Messaging.InboundEnvelope env){

        Messaging.InboundEmailResult result = new Messaging.InboundEmailResult();

        String myPlainText= '';
        Contact c;
        myPlainText = email.plainTextBody;

        try{
            if([SELECT count() from Contact where email =:email.fromAddress] == 0){
                c = new Contact();
                c.LastName = email.fromName;
                c.Email = email.fromAddress;
                insert c; 
            }
            else{
                c = [SELECT Id from Contact Where email =:email.fromAddress LIMIT 1];
            }

            Trade_Support__c ts = new Trade_Support__c();
            ts.Description__c = myPlainText;
            ts.Status__c = 'New';
            ts.Subject__c = email.subject;
            ts.web_email__c = email.fromAddress;
            ts.contact__c = c.Id;
            insert ts;

            EmailMessage mail = new EmailMessage();
            mail.Subject = email.subject;
            mail.FromAddress = email.fromAddress;
            mail.HtmlBody = email.htmlBody;
            mail.TextBody = myPlainText;
            mail.FromName = email.fromName;
            mail.RelatedToId = ts.Id;
            //this is where I have the issue
            //mail.toAddress = email.toAddresses;
            //mail.CcAddress = email.ccAddresses;

            mail.Status = 'Read';
            insert mail;

            // Save attachments, if any
                List<Attachment> attachments = new List<Attachment>();
                if(email.textAttachments != null)
                {
                    for (Messaging.Inboundemail.TextAttachment tAttachment : email.textAttachments) {
                        Attachment attachment = new Attachment();
                        attachment.Name = tAttachment.fileName;
                        attachment.Body = Blob.valueOf(tAttachment.body);
                        attachment.ParentId = ts.Id;
                        attachments.add(attachment);
                    }
                }
                if(email.binaryAttachments != null)
                {
                    for (Messaging.Inboundemail.BinaryAttachment bAttachment : email.binaryAttachments) {
                        Attachment attachment = new Attachment();

                        attachment.Name = bAttachment.fileName;
                        attachment.Body = bAttachment.body;
                        attachment.ParentId = ts.Id;
                        attachments.add(attachment);
                    }
                }
                if(attachments.size() > 0)
                {
                    insert attachments;
                }


        }
        catch (QueryException e) {
            System.debug('Query Issue:  ' + e);
        }

        result.success = true;

        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Next time just post the code that's relevant to your question.  Scrolling through the whole file takes time :-)

Comment: My apologies.  Didn't think that one through before posting.

Comment: Never, *ever* catch an exception if you are going to take no subsequent action (and no, debugging doesn't count as an action).

Answer (score 4):

toAddresses is a `List<String>`, so you need to join the values together:

```
mail.toAddress = String.join(email.toAddresses, ',');
```

You'll want to check the CC Address list to make sure it's not null before attempting to call `join` on it.

Comment: Did you intend `String.join(email.toAddresses, ',')` instead?

Comment: @JayantDas Yeah... Let's say I've been writing too much JS lately.

Answer (score 2):

The error on the line below is because [`EmailMessage.toAddress`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfFieldRef.meta/sfFieldRef/salesforce_field_reference_EmailMessage.htm) is of type `String` and that [`Messaging.InboundEmail.toAddresses`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_email_inbound_inbound.htm) returns a `String[]`

```
mail.toAddress = email.toAddresses; // results in illegal assignment that you are facing
```

To fix this you will need to extract the `String` value from the `email.toAddresses` and assign accordingly. Something as:

```
mail.toAddress = String.join(email.toAddresses, ',');
```